# Laravel framework eloquent relationship query

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have created relationship between 4 tables.

This are my models:

- `User`
- `BusinessInfo`
- `ElectrcityInfo`
- `GasInfo`

This are the primery keys that I am using in my tables:

- `user_id`  (to get login users data from `BusinessInfo`)
- `contract_id` (This also exists in `BusinessInfo` I am use it to get data from the other two tables for specific records)

Now I want to get all login users data from `BusinessInfo` table and each `BusinessInfo` row has its own 1 row data from `ElectricityInfo` and `GasInfo`.

When I am use `contract_id` in model its give me relationship result `null`.
When it is on `user_id` its display only 1 `ElectrcityInfo` with all records.

**Controller**

```php
$user = Auth::user();
$business = BusinessInfo::where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
$data = $business->electricity()->paginate(6);

return view('Pages.MySite', ['data' => $data]);
```

**BusinessInfo Model**

```php
protected $primaryKey = 'contract_id';
public $table = "business_info";
protected $guarded = [];
public $timestamps = false;

public function electricity()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ElectricityInfo', 'contract_id');
}

public function gas()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\GasInfo', 'contract_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You **BusinessInfo** model is missing the `user` relationship. Put this in your code:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id');
}
```

Your query is not right

> When it is on user_id its display only 1 ElectrcityInfo with all records.

This is because you use the `first()` method wich returns the first object from the collection. You should use this:

```
$businesses = BusinessInfo::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
```

This will return all objects according to the query.

Now you can loop the `$business` array and access each information

```
foreach($businesses as $business)
{
 $business->electricity()->first(); // this will return all your data from the BusinessInfo relation with the ElectricityInfo model
 $business->gas()->first(); // this will return all your data from the BusinessInfo relation with the GasInfo model
}
```

For more info about the [`first()` method and other methods click here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-first)

You also could take a look at the [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) section to know more about how it works

In your view:

```
@foreach($businesses as $business)
{
 {{$business->electricity()->first()}}
 {{$business->gas()->first()}}
}
@endforeach
```

Comment: #related: ElectricityInfo {#267 ▼
    #primaryKey: "contract_id"
    +table: "electricity_info"
    +timestamps: false
    #connection: "mysql"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: false
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: []
    #original: []
    #changes: []
    #casts: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #dispatchesEvents: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: []
    #touches: []
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #fillable: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  }  **Its still null**

Comment: You sure you DB is seeded? Also make sure to add the relations  on the ElectricityInfo model and in the GasInfo model

Comment: I got result by using $business->electricity->mpan its give me only 1 data with each business I want to get each business its own electricity

Comment: Try using this: $business->electricity()->first() this should return all information with in the ElectricityInfo model

Comment: Still same result with all records same mpan value display in table its not get next record value

Comment: Are you using dd() to print this information? use var_dump() instead. Put on the question what did you get plis.

Comment: Instead of using Model::where have you tried Model::has 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: @LucasPiazzi yes I am using dd() but now I try var_dump its iterate foreach loop in controller and give me all records according to my requirement but when I am using same foreach in blade template page die due to iterate.

Comment: @LucasPiazzi Still same result not change mpan with next record